# (Processing 4.0) Is there a way to draw with the arc()-function starting with a higher degree and going to a lower degree?

Tags: processing

like   `arc(200, 200, 195, 195, radians(270), radians(40));`
Sitting in class right now and could need some help with that.

Comment: Which API is that ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Read the tag info [tag:processing]. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Comment: The doc says "the start/stop values must be in clockwise order", which probably does not mean "the start value must be smaller than the stop". But here just swapping the two arguments should work (otherwise you get the complement to a full turn).